# Trouble retrieving custom taxonomy meta field value in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked around and I am unable to see anything that can help me retrieve a custom meta field value in single.php. Below is what i have tried thus far, but i am unsuccessful:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'taxonomy' => 'locations',
  ); 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$terms->term_id" );  
$categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p><strong>' . $category->name . '</strong></p> ';
    echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . echo $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] . '</p>';
} 
?>
```

The expected result should look like this:

New York (name)
212 Broadway, NY NY 10001 (description)
212-123-1234 (custom taxonomy meta field value)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that it's the curly quotes `‘ ’` and `“ ”` causing the problem, which should have thrown an error, had [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) been enabled and displayed.

Change them to `'` and `"` respectively:

```
$args = array(
'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'taxonomy' => 'locations',
);
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$terms->term_id" );
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
echo '<p>' . $category->name . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . $category->description . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . echo $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] . '</p>';
}
```

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help finding errors.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- *Thanks to Daniel Cooley for his input on this.*

---

This was most likely caused by using MS Word or similar word processing software.

- It's best to use an actual [**"code" editor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor).

Comment: Never add error_reporting to a "production" environment... you should create a staging environment and show errors there.  You are just asking to be hacked!

Comment: So is that why you downvoted me, if that is your downvote? @DanielCooley

Comment: @DanielCooley Suggesting OP to add error reporting is something a developer must always use when coding. If I worded it wrong then that's my mistake, which I've rectified by replacing it with "which will help finding errors.". I'm always open to suggestions.

Comment: Agreed... but suggesting that it only be done in a staging environment, and never in production, is also something a developer must do.  There are a lot of people who don't know any better and will implement your suggestion in a production environment, simply because they haven't been warned of the repercussions.  You should edit your post again to make it clear that your error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @DanielCooley I couldn't agree with you more Daniel, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @DanielCooley I've edited it with a mention in there. Appreciate the input Daniel and I will make a note of it for future postings, *cheers*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks for the advice. I actually do you a "code" editor. It was just a bad copy paste job (my apologies). Unfortunately that does not solve the actual problem at hand.